# Easy way to take ownership of a Registry key in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, registry

I am creating a VB.NET application and I want that application to be able to take ownership of few Registry keys.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. Someone suggested to me a complex procedure that requires about 300 lines of code. It seems to me that is too much effort for what is conceptually an easy task.

So, is there a straightforward way to change or take ownership of a Registry key?

Comment: What means "take ownership" : is it just read/write/delete registry key ?

Comment: @Graffito Like files and kernal objects registry keys have full access control lists in Windows, including a user (or group) as owner.

Comment: I never realized that registry provided a mean to set-up autorisations :(.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the current user has the necessary rights to take ownership:

- Get a [`RegistryKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) instance for the key.
- Call [`GetAccessControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w66447a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the ACL.
- Call [`SetOwner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setowner.aspx) on the ACL passing the necessary user identity.
- Call [`SetAccessControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setaccesscontrol.aspx) to replace the ACL on the registry key.

(I suspect the 300 lines of code was using P/Invoke from the days before the .NET framework had support for reading and manipulating ACLs.)

Comment: Seems on right path but unable to understand how to use GetAccessControl and SetOwner. Suppose we are giving permissions to "users". Any example?

Comment: @ParasSidhu : To add an access control entry (ACE) to the ACL is more complex (you need to deal with ACE ordering and handling the identity already having an ACE). What is the problem with those methods? (`GetAccessControl` returns an object which has `SetOwner` as a method.)

Comment: Hello @Richard, Actually I am a beginner. Or atleast not expert. When I use SetOwner method, it asks for identity: The owner to set. Just don't know how to put or set "users" in it

Comment: @ParasSidhu An instance of `WindowsIdenttiy` will do. Eg. [`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0.aspx) to get an identity instance for the current user.

Comment: So I declared x as some registry key and then

Comment: x.GetAccessControl.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Owner) but that doesn't seem to work. Nothing changing

Comment: @ParasSidhu "doesn't seem to work" does not tell me anything. Remember you need to apply the updated ACL to the `RegistryKey` instance.

Comment: Hi there, I'm really sorry. I am 1 Year late to reply. Finally I got the code working for me. What I have used:   'Dim regkey As RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Directory\Shell\cmd", True)

            Dim access As RegistrySecurity = regkey.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Owner)
            access.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Owner)
            regkey.SetAccessControl(access)'

Comment: In 'regkey', Shell key had permissions set to "System". By using the code, I changed its permissions to "Administrator" successfully. Now the only problem is when  I try to do the same for "cmd" key whose owner is "TrustedInstaller", it throws SecurityException since it can't read the key. I want to know how can I take ownership of a key whose owner is TrustedInstaller. Thanks!

Comment: @ParasSidhu If you cannot read the ACL you cannot read the ACL. To even replace it you need some rights to the key in question. A user with take ownership privilege can do so, but using that privilege is far beyond the scope of a comment. Summary: you need to create a new question that specifies the current ACL and the details of the process's security token.